# How consumer QueueChannel with some rate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46979728/1251549) is example how fill and process queue. But how process message with rate? Like process `N` messages per second?

**UPDATE**
Here by "porcess": I meant "dequeue". E.g. how to dequeue N messages per second?

Comment: What do you mean by "process"? You can control how many messages you want to dequeue per second with simple math when implementing your loop conditions. But processing (a.k.a. acting on the message) is controlled by user own code, so there is absolutely no way to estimate in any kind of general way. You may have a code that can dequeue a 100 messages per second, but the actual process of a single message let's say takes a min. . . and so on

Comment: Thnaks for quick reply. Question updated. I meant dequeing rate

Answer (score 0):

You can wrote a loop as I mentioned earlier with some kind of rate control (e.g, via Thread.sleep as the most rudimentary).
You can also try to use @Scheduled annotation.

Here is the example of a method that will be invoked 100 times per second

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10)
public void dequeue() {
        //queue.poll(..)
}
```